# In bash script how to exit a if else condition , if the 'if' condition is true

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I am trying to check whether a process is running or not in a bash script . This function is part of the script .
So in this bash script I have enabled `-e` and now this function is failing for the condition when the service is already not running because in else the value of PID is empty .

I want this function to exit at the if condition the pid doesn't exist without error and rest of the script will continue , but it's breaking .
I can run it without `set -e` , but is their any way to run it with `set -e`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
stop_service () {
    pid=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep process.jar | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [ ! -d "/proc/$pid" ]; then
           echo "already not running" #exit the loop
    else
        echo "killing $pid"
        kill $pid

    fi
}
stop_service
```

Comment: Use `break` to exit a loop. But I don't see any loop in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the script to *exit*, use the `exit` command. If you want the function to *return* so that the rest of the script can continue, use `return` as I have done here.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

stop_service () {
    pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/[p]rocess.jar/ {print $2; exit}')
    if [[ -n "$pid" && -d "/proc/$pid" ]]; then
        echo "killing $pid" >&2
        kill "$pid" || :
    else
        echo "process is not running" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}

stop_service
```

Notice that in your original code, if `pid` was empty then the directory expression `"/proc/$pid"` would have been reduced to `"/proc/"`, and so the test would have still succeeded. I'm not entirely sure why you want to check the directory `/proc/$pid` anyway, since by definition it will exist on a Linux-based system if you have found its entry in the process table; however, I've left that check in my revised code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check if $pid is set before you kill it, then you shouldn't get the error.

You can check if your variable is empty as follows (according to [this website](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-script-check-if-variable-is-empty/)):

```
if [ -z "$var" ]
then
      echo "\$var is empty"
else
      echo "\$var is NOT empty"
fi
```